# Getting JSON Object when the page is reloaded

Tags: mysql, node.js, json, angular

I made an angular application and I made a NodeJS API which is running on different port from the angular application. I made a call to the API and displayed the returned JSON data on the gallery component which is a routed component. But when I reloaded the page I am only seeing my JSON data written but no gallery component. How can this be fixed? Thanks in advance!

**This is my gallery component ts file.**

```
import { DbConnectService } from '../db-connect.service';
interface GalleryItem {
  path : String
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-gallery',
  templateUrl: './gallery.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./gallery.component.css']
})
export class GalleryComponent implements OnInit {
  galleryitem:any;
  p:any = 1;
  count: any = 2;
  constructor(private gallery : DbConnectService) {

    this.gallery.getgallery().subscribe((galleryitems) =>{
      this.galleryitem= galleryitems;
    })

  }
  ngOnInit(){
  }
}
```

**This is my API file**

```
const bodyparser = require("body-parser")
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const mysql = require("mysql");

app.use(bodyparser.json());

const conn = mysql.createConnection({
  host:"localhost",
  user:"root",
  password:"",
  database:"youngshoulders_gallery"
})

conn.connect((err)=>{
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log("mysql connected");
})

app.get("/gallery",(req,res)=>{
  let sql = "SELECT * FROM GALLERY";
  let query = conn.query(sql,(err,result)=>{
    if(err) throw err;
    res.send(result);
  })
})

app.listen(8000);
```

**This is the data returned when API is called**
[OUTPUT WHEN API IS CALLED](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxDSb.png)

**This is the returned JSON data after reloading the above page**
[JSON Output when page reloaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNi0w.png)

Comment: My guess: you are using angular routing to show the `GalleryComponent`, and the route name matches the one used by he API. Both routes are named `gallery`, right?

Comment: @R.Richards Yes! You guessed that right! Is this the problem? How can I get it fixed?

Comment: Make the route for the API something like `/api/gallery`, and update the DB service to use that when calling the API.

Comment: Yep , that worked! I understood where the problem was but why it was coming?